# Adding a Phone number in conference

Tags: api, voice, sinch, conferencing

So I'm trying to use [Sinch](https://www.sinch.com/) API for making a calling application.
I'm using this to make a conference call, but the call is only made to first person and plays the message that "You are the only person in this conference" and hangs up after a while.
[Documentation](https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#Callouts) writes that The same API can be used multiple times to connect multiple phone numbers in the same conference room. But couldn't made to do the task. Also contacted the support but no answer yet.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: any luck on that? I'm trying to do exactly the same but I couldn't make the second call actually ring in the second phone. It's weird because the response from the second request is fine and the server creates a `callId`.

Answer (score 0):

Waquar the following works perfect for me calling feel free to add my number and give me a call +15612600684  https://callingapi.sinch.com/v1/callouts
First

```
{
    "method" : "conferenceCallout",
    "conferenceCallout" :
    {
        "cli" : "46000000000",
        "destination" : { "type" : "number", "endpoint" : "+14154251021" },
        "domain" : "pstn",
        "custom" : "customData",
        "locale" : "en-US",
        "greeting" : "Welcome to my conference",
        "conferenceId" : "coolconf",
        "enableDice" : false
    }
}
```

and then

```
{
    "method" : "conferenceCallout",
    "conferenceCallout" :
    {
        "cli" : "46000000000",
        "destination" : { "type" : "number", "endpoint" : "+15612600684" },
        "domain" : "pstn",
        "custom" : "customData",
        "locale" : "en-US",
        "greeting" : "Welcome to my conference",
        "conferenceId" : "coolconf",
        "enableDice" : false
    }
}
```

Comment: It rings on the first but not on the second phone? Are you waiting a long time between the requests?

Comment: 1st call is made instantly, but it says that "You are the only person in this conference" and hangs up

Comment: Hey @cjencen, for me it also doesn't work. I tried to wait 10 seconds, 1 minute and even answering the first call and then calling the second.

Comment: Do you have money in your account?

Comment: Maybe you can mail support@sinch.com with your account details so we can check the balance